# Attach an iCalendar event to a mail in Grails

Tags: email, grails, arrays, icalendar, email-attachments

I've been working with Grails 3.x, specifically with mail and iCalendar plugins, I tried to attach an iCalendar event to my mail Service but it didn't work. I would appreciate so much if someone could help me to fix my code. Here it is:

** This part is my iCalendar structure ** https://github.com/saw303/grails-ic-alender

```
byte[] iCalendarFile
{
    render(contentType: 'text/calendar') 
    {
        calendar 
        {
            events {
                event(
                    start: new Date(), 
                    end: new Date(), 
                    description: 'Event', 
                    summary: 'Some text here', 
                )
            }
        }
    }
    calendar.toString.getBytes('UTF-8')
}
```

** And then I have my email structure **

```
def mailService

def emailSender() 
{
    mailService.sendMail 
    {
      multipart true
      to correo
      subject "Event" 
      body "Some text here"
      attach "audiencia.ics", "text/calendar", iCalendarFile ()
    }
}
```

Both iCalendarFile and emailSender are in the same Service class.

Thanks for yout support. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer

```
import ch.silviowangler.grails.icalender.ICalendarBuilder

class NotifierService 
{
    byte[] emailFile (**params**)
    {
        def archivo = new ICalendarBuilder()
        archivo.calendar {
            events {
                event( start: new Date(), 
                   end: new Date(), 
                   description: "Description", 
                   summary: "Some text here",
                   utc: true // optional
                ) 
            }
       }
       archivo.cal.toString().getBytes('UTF-8')
    }

mailService.sendMail 
{
    multipart true
    to email@email.com
    subject "Subject" 
    body "Some text here"
    attach "event.ics", "text/calendar", emailFile(**params**)
}
```